# JS ошибка не находит картинку: GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/js%20exam/img/pipeBottom.png 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript

Я пишу браузерную игру по видеоуроку, но у меня появилась проблема при написании кода на JS. Проблема в том, что JS: **bird.src = "../img/bird.png";** выводит ошибку.
Я искал в интернете, но не нашел.
Директория правильно, картинка существует.
Пробовал в HTML картинка загрузилась, но в JS нет.
Помогите решить эту проблему!
Спасибо.
Вот программный код:

```js
var cvs = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = cvs.getContext('2d');

/**
 * **********************************
 * LOADING GAME RESOURCES
 * **********************************
 */

//loading images
var bird = new Image();
var bg = new Image();
var fg = new Image();
var pipeUp = new Image();
var pipeBottom = new Image();

bird.src = "../img/bird.png";
bg.src = "../img/bg.png";
fg.src = "../img/fg.png";
pipeUp.src = "../img/pipeUp.png";
pipeBottom.src = "../img/pipeBottom.png";

/**
 * **********************************
 * CODE
 * **********************************
 */
//draw function
function draw() {
    ctx.drawImage(bg, 0, 0);
}
pipeBottom.onload = draw();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Flappy Bird!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="288" height="512"></canvas>
    <img src="./img/bird.png" alt="" srcset="">
    <script src="./js/game.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: %20 - это бробел)

Comment: а вы пробовали без точек? `bird.src = "../img/bird.png";` -> `bird.src = "./img/bird.png";`

Comment: Да. Сработала!!

Comment: пропишу это как ответ тогда)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уберите одну точку от src:

```
bird.src = "./img/bird.png";
bg.src = "./img/bg.png";
fg.src = "./img/fg.png";
pipeUp.src = "./img/pipeUp.png";
pipeBottom.src = "./img/pipeBottom.png";
```